# In Node.js connected to Geth : solc.compile prefixes an additional ':' before contractName

Tags: solidity, nodejs, solc, compiler

I'm trying the following script on Node.js while running a node connected to Rinkeby Testnet (from  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require('solc')

let source = fs.readFileSync('nameContract.sol', 'utf8');
let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
let abi = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].interface;
let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].bytecode;
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode});
let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
```

However, this code doesn't work on my computer: when I log `compiledContract` I can see that the key in the mapping is `:nameContract` and not `nameContract`.

When I replace in the code `nameContract` by `:nameContract`, it works.
I've checked my Solidity file and there is no mistyping errors in it.

Do you have an idea why this happens? I'm using Git BASH on Windows10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this comes a bit late, but it's not a bug, it's a feature, see [Contract name starts with colon in compiled output](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/91):

- Report:

> `solc.compile(exampleContract)` returns the following. It would be good
>   to remove colon before contract name.
>
> ```
> {
>   "contracts": {
>      ":NameOfContract": {...}
>   }
> }
> ```

- Resolution:

> To make contract references unambiguous in the output, newer compiler versions prefix every contract with :. This will be further expanded in the next version where a proper json object will be returned, so please stay tuned for a "fix".

- Note:

> I close this as it is not a "bug", just how the compiler works.